# Activity life cycle creating,starting and running procedure

Tags: android

If my first activity is just an image, and my second activity is a song and a calculator. So If I start my second activity and then I make a sleep on my first activity for 5000ms and then kill it... will sound will play while my first activity's image is on the screen? And where will be my calculator during sleep period ?

Comment: I am not able to understand creation,resuming,pasuing cycle of activity.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you "sleep" your first `Activity`, assuming you are talking about the `UI` thread and not a background thread, then your whole `UI` will sleep for that time...meaning your second Activity won't be started yet and your song won't play.

What you could do is put it all in one `Activity` and put your image and calculator in the same position, or wherever you want in the layout, and hide your calculator from the beginning in your xml with

```
 android:visibility="invisible" // or gone depending on what you need
```

Then you can change the visibility of both views when you need. I don't know exactly what you want so I don't know if this solution is suitable.

You also could look into putting your song in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: To add to the answer http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html. You should not block your ui thread.

Comment: What's the difference between UI thread and background thread?

Comment: Ui is the main thread where you can uupdate ui. thread runs in the background. you can do network related operation. But you cannot update ui from the background thread.

Comment: @user2609410 The `UI Thread` is what you are looking at when you're app is open...TextView's, EditText, etc...are on the `UI` thread and can only be updated from there. Background threads are just that, they run in the background as to not interrupt the UI for things like downloading data

Comment: Laucher will start my first activity. Then how do i go to next activity?

Comment: With `Intent`. But if you don't know that then you really need to read the [Getting Started Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Comment: While my first activity is running, and through intent i start my second activity. Which activity prevails? Like which Will be shown on screen?

Comment: Your second Activity will be shown and your first will be behind it if you don't finish it.

Comment: @user2609410 pls check the activity lifecycle. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html. your questions will be answered if you check the docs.

Comment: I am not able to understand creation,resuming,pasuing cycle. Explain please .

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I can explain it any better than the docs do without a specific question. You may need to read through them several times, I did.